# Draw QGraphicsRectItems with negative values

Tags: c++, qt, drawing, draw

I am actually implementing a class which allows the user to draw as many rectangles as he wants while he is pressing the mouse.

Here is the code of the `QGraphicsScene` which deals with that situation:

```
void ImageGraphicsSceneW::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
  origPoint=event->scenePos();
  qDebug()<<"origPoint="<<origPoint;
  mousePressed=true;

  QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(event);
}

void ImageGraphicsSceneW::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
  if(mousePressed==true){
    if(!rectangle){
      rectangle=new QGraphicsRectItem;
      this->addItem(rectangle);
      rectangle->setPen(QPen(Qt::red,4,Qt::SolidLine));
      rectangle->setPos(origPoint);
    }
    qDebug()<<"event.scenePos.x:"<<event->scenePos();
    rectangle->setRect(0,0,(event->scenePos().x()-origPoint.x()),
      (event->scenePos().y()-origPoint.y()));
  }
  else
    QGraphicsScene::mouseMoveEvent(event);
}

void ImageGraphicsSceneW::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
  rectangle=NULL;
  //buffer_rectangle(0,0,0,0);
  mousePressed=false;
  QGraphicsScene::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
}
```

However, I have some problems when I actually want to draw rectangles with negatives width and height. I mean when the values of `origPoint.x()` and `origPoint.y()` are strictly higher than `scenePos().x()` and `scenePos().y()` respectively.

Do you have any idea of how I can deal with this problem? Do I have to use the `QTransform` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `x` or `y` of `event->scenePos()` become lower than origin point adjust origin point to the topmost and leftmost point and take positive width value:

```
void mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
  if(mousePressed==true){
    if(!rectangle){
      rectangle=new QGraphicsRectItem;
      this->addItem(rectangle);
      rectangle->setPen(QPen(Qt::red,4,Qt::SolidLine));
      rectangle->setPos(origPoint);
    }

    float top = qMin(origPoint.y(), event->scenePos().y());
    float left = qMin(origPoint.x(), event->scenePos().x());
    rectangle->setPos(left, top);
    rectangle->setRect(0, 0, qAbs(event->scenePos().x() - origPoint.x()),
      qAbs(event->scenePos().y() - origPoint.y()));

    qDebug() << top << left << origPoint << event->scenePos();
  }
  else
    QGraphicsScene::mouseMoveEvent(event);
}
```